# Optimize finding the next batch of data from A to be crunched and inserted into B

Tags: postgresql, database-design, performance, query-performance

I'm using PostgreSQL to store data produced by a large distributed computation.  There are several stages to this computation; the idiom we've settled on is that there's a table containing the results of each stage.  The relevant tables for the stage I'm working on right now look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE job_global (
    id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    data  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE stageA_results (
    jobid  INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES job_global(id)
    -- several more columns
);
CREATE INDEX stageA_results__jobid ON stageA_results(jobid);

CREATE TABLE stageB_results (
    locale TEXT NOT NULL,
    jobid  INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES job_global(id),
    -- several more columns
    PRIMARY KEY(locale, jobid)
);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE stageB_queue (
    ix     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    jobid  INTEGER NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO stageB_queue (jobid)
    SELECT DISTINCT jobid FROM stageA_results ORDER BY random();

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE stageB_processing (
    locale TEXT NOT NULL,
    jobid  INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

To give an idea of the scale, there are currently 5,361,151 unique `jobid` values in `stageA_results`, and each one of those will ultimately generate order of 10 rows in `stageB_results`.

Now, populating `stageB_results` involves, as I mentioned, a large distributed computation.  There is a single dispatcher process for that computation.  Periodically, it needs to retrieve the next block of job IDs which have not yet been processed in a particular "locale".  The query I have for that right now is

```
SELECT q.jobid, jg.data
     FROM stageB_queue q
LEFT JOIN stageB_results br    ON q.jobid = br.jobid
LEFT JOIN stageB_processing bp ON q.jobid = bp.jobid
     JOIN job_global jg        ON q.jobid = jg.id

WHERE (br.jobid IS NULL OR br.locale <> $locale)
  AND (bp.jobid IS NULL OR bp.locale <> $locale)

ORDER BY q.ix
LIMIT 20; -- example number, this order of magnitude
```

This query is fast when `stageB_results` and `stageB_processing` are both empty, but if there are even a handful of rows in either, it takes several minutes to run.  It needs to be efficient across the entire spectrum of possibilities for what's in `stageB_results` -- from zero to 50 million rows; from almost no rows weeded out by the anti-joins, to almost all of them.  There will typically be order of 5000 rows in `stageB_processing`, but they change constantly.  (The next step is to insert all of the jobids that this query returns into that table; when the worker machines report results for those jobids, they are removed again.)

Adding indexes on the various `jobid` columns did not help, so I presume I need to structure the query differently, but I'm out of ideas.  Please also feel free to tell me to reorganize my tables; this is the first time I've tried to do something this large with an RDBMS so I can easily imagine those being poorly laid out.

Here's an EXPLAIN ANALYZE dump (sorry it's so wide) taken with 4000 artificial rows in `stageB_results` and nothing in `stageB_processing`:

```
 Limit  (cost=117756.30..117756.30 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=165471.693..165471.753 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=117756.30..117756.30 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=165471.684..165471.704 rows=20 loops=1)
         Sort Key: q.ix
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=116.44..117756.29 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=21.241..157039.067 rows=5357151 loops=1)
               ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=116.00..117748.89 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=21.204..51436.760 rows=5357151 loops=1)
                     Join Filter: (q.jobid = bp.jobid)
                     Filter: ((bp.jobid IS NULL) OR (bp.locale <> 'xx'::text))
                     ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=116.00..117708.14 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=21.192..22403.874 rows=5357151 loops=1)
                           Hash Cond: (q.jobid = br.jobid)
                           Filter: ((br.jobid IS NULL) OR (br.locale <> 'xx'::text))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 4000
                           ->  Seq Scan on stageB_queue q  (cost=0.00..77333.51 rows=5361151 width=8) (actual time=0.014..6630.440 rows=5361151 loops=1)
                           ->  Hash  (cost=66.00..66.00 rows=4000 width=7) (actual time=10.878..10.878 rows=4000 loops=1)
                                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 153kB
                                 ->  Seq Scan on stageB_results br  (cost=0.00..66.00 rows=4000 width=7) (actual time=0.006..5.279 rows=4000 loops=1)
                     ->  Seq Scan on stageB_processing bp  (cost=0.00..22.30 rows=1230 width=36) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=5357151)
               ->  Index Scan using job_global_pkey on job_global jg  (cost=0.43..7.38 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=0.013..0.015 rows=1 loops=5357151)
                     Index Cond: (id = q.jobid)
 Total runtime: 165471.831 ms
```